# Two mono sound sources into one stereo aux cable

Tags: amplifier, circuit-design, audio, stereo

I have two entirely separate mono line-level audio sources. I want to plug them both into a stereo aux speaker, where one sound source goes through the left side of the aux speaker and other goes through the right side of the aux speaker.

Can I just connect it as such or do I need some type of resistors or circuitry in there to prevent damage:

Source1+ --> Tip of 3.5 mm jack
Source2+ --> Ring of 3.5 mm jack
Source1- & Source2- --> Sleeve of 3.5 mm jack

Technically these sources are run by two different sound chips inside two toys, but run off same battery source.

Comment: It depends which kind of output the devices have. If they just have a line out connector, you can buy adapters and likely be done with it. If you intend to replace a speaker with output connector, that's unknown territory without schematics, especially when they run off of same battery source. If they are unconnectable directly, no resistors will help. But I will close this as product usage question.

Comment: It is replacing a speaker with an output connector. Is there anything that I should put in between to make sure it doesn’t get ruined? Or should I use a small powered 2 channel mixer? Or something else? Schematics are hard on this one. It’s the Hasbro ghostbusters wand and pack. Both the wand and pack have audio coming from them and I want to make it louder and better sounding with a external speaker

Comment: There may be a way but since we don't know how the device drives the original speaker, we can't possibly know in which way to safely connect it to a line output connector. Except if you buy audio transformers to isolate the line output. Also if they share a battery, they are not completely sparate audio sources any more. The original audio sources may just have speaker positive connected to battery positive and then the speaker negative is driven in open collector mode. Or the speaker is driven with a H bridge where both speaker wires are active and cannot be connectes together.

Comment: Do you have room for 2 opamp?

Comment: Yes I do have room for opamps

Comment: @IanGendel, well then join them for a simple (eurorack) "summing mixer" on 2 opamps and these 2 output to a stereo jack.

Comment: @NaturalDemon That still leaves the problem of how to replace the original speaker with an op-amp. The problem was not to mix the signals, but how to replace speakers of original devices in a way that you can use standard TRS connector which requires that both devices share a ground. So op-amps do not solve the original problem.

Comment: @Justme he states in the question, the devices share the same power supply. i used to drive with a Sony Walkman powered on a battery to a (aftermarket) car amplifier powered by the alternator/car battery and it worked great. GND assumes the same potentional, otherwise you could go the expensive route and use "NEUTRIK NTE10-3" transformers at 10€ each on each device to be sure, no ground loops arise.

Comment: @Justme I don't mind having both be mixed into a single mono audio out. I just was originally trying to make it easier by "keeping them separate" and using one on left speaker, one on right speaker, thinking it would prevent causing issues with blowing anything out. But thinking about it, they share a negative so this won't work. That's why I am open to doing anything to either combine the signals and get a mono output, or do my original plan of one on left and one on right with stereo connector

Comment: @NaturalDemon If I use opamps to combine the signals as a mixer do you think I have to use the transformer? Technically it goes battery to electronics board on first sound source that has a speaker on it. That electronics board then feeds power to electronics board on second sound source that has a second speaker on it. I want these 2 sound sources then to go to a external bluetooth speaker with an aux cable

Comment: You could try to to power all devices from the same power supply than no transformers are needed, no ground loops will arise, if you wanna use the battery powered devices have their own power source, you could try to use these "Neutrik" audio transformers, but they are round 10€ each (they are small and fragil) it's than isolated, like these DI boxes they use on stage for guitars, keyboards, microphones and what not on "long" cables, your choice on how much money you wanna spend on it.

Comment: Neutrik NTE10/3 1:3:10, Neutrik NTE1, Neutrik NTE4, depending how you use them, you can amplify (without using additional power) the signal by using them in reverse, like the Neutrik NTE10 or decrease the amplitute without a cost. than you could use JEFT opamp's to amplify again.

Comment: @NaturalDemon Yeah but sharing a power supply means nothing. These are toys. Just like car stereos, both positive and negative speaker wires can be "live" signals, and neither one is ground.

Comment: @Justme Very true. That's how I realized it was a bad idea. I'm looking at now building an opamp 2 channel mixer. Just not sure if it should also have an isolation transformer in it too just to make sure